# i enter "rm -rf /obj" and my system is broked

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

i enter "rm -rf /obj" erroneous .now my system is broken! :( for example i enter ls terminal return : OH NO i go to copy terminal massage ,my system on sleep mode! now i enter pass dm returns : pass incorrect (!). dm is freeze. i want to restart the os. in power tab power off or reboot and etc. not existence ! (my ubuntu in a VMware vm) i restart my vm and in start Linux i see many errors and next i see this : my sys err i very sad. .please help me!!!!!!!!!
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLvia.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is usually no /obj directory on Linux, are you sure that was the command? Did you run it as root?

Comment: Also please provide exact error- and other messages you see, otherwise it's simply not possible to even guess what's going on.

Comment: yes i in root.see this  photo https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLvia.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The photo shows that even /bin/sh isn't found, starting DNS resolution fails, even mounting file systems fail.

As @golimar already said, /obj is not part of any standard Linux installation. [It's not part of Ubuntu either.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview) However /bin *is*, and /bin/sh *always* exists unless you delete it. To me it looks like you've actually deleted one or more standard Linux root directories. The most sensible way forward is to just create a new VM.

Comment: thanks. i can recover my files?

Comment: I forgot now! I also deleted the bin directory by mistake. I had a makefile that had a clean function and inside it it deleted the contents of two different directory that were in my project. One of them was the directory It was bin! And I first put the address of an extra '/'. Now I understand that the problem was with the latter, which was the bin directory. Thanks @ Peregrino69